# How to catch event when RNBlurModalView close in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I used `RNBlurModalView` , but now I want to call a new `function` when `RNBlurModalView` 
disappears.

How can I do that?

Comment: you can call your function after `hide` method,
or you want to call it before `disappear RNBlurModalView`?

Comment: yes i know but how can call my function when user click on CLose button on RNBlurModalView? Because method of Close button is wrote on RNBlurModalView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incidentally there are three ways(may be more):

**Way 1:** Use this method to hide your `RNBlurModalView` object and use the Completion Handler block to call the function(you want to call) when it is hidden.

```
- (void)hideWithDuration:(CGFloat)duration delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options completion:(void (^)(void))completion;
```

**Way 2:** You can listen for `kRNBlurDidHidewNotification` NSNotification to know whether the view has been hidden or not.

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self 
                                          selector:@selector(modalViewHides:) 
                                              name:kRNBlurDidHidewNotification
                                            object:nil];
```

**Way 3:** Use Key-Value Observing on the `isVisible` property.

```
[modal addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isVisible" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:NULL];
```

**Example:::**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    RNBlurModalView *modal = [[RNBlurModalView alloc] initWithViewController:self title:@"Hello world!" message:@"Pur your message here."];
    [modal show];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                          selector:@selector(modalViewHides)
                                              name:kRNBlurDidHidewNotification
                                            object:nil];
}

- (void)modalViewHides
{
 // call your function 
}
```

Comment: call this function is my class or RNBlurModalView class?

Comment: Can you example code? I don't understand clearly . Thanks much

Comment: Yes, it works now. Can you help me one more times? I have a problem with uitableview, can you help me? Please see at here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358998/can-not-change-image-uibutton-in-uitableview-after-reloaddata-ios . Thanks

Comment: The question is not formatted properly and is hard to understand, plus I feel you need to do some research first on your side before posting questions to SO. I would encourage you to read as many docs as possible and still if you stuck somewhere SO community will definitely help you.

Comment: @Puneet , I have two buttons in my modal view (cancel & ok). How can I access these? At the moment I'm crashing when either button is pressed. They work if I just use a normal modal, but not with the RNBlurModalView.  Thanks

Comment: @Jorgen, if you haven't got answered yet, you can access the buttons inside the modal view by looping through the subviews inside the modal view. To add an action to a button, you just have to set the target to each button you added to the modal view.