# Can not change image uibutton in uitableview after reloadData iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I create a tableview has button, this button has been changed image ass different condition. The first load tableview, these buttons set image correct but after condition change, it set image incorrect. Example : If [Selling = 0] , set image "Market.png", else [Selling =2], set image "MarketSelect.png". When value of Selling array changing, i used [_tableview reloadData] but it still not change image. I debug, i see MarketButton is 0x0000. The first load, MarketButton works correct but second load, it is 0x0000. Please give me advice to solve this problem. I tried 2 days but it can not works. thanks much

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (nil == cell) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.button.tag = indexPath.row;
                UIButton *market = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                [market setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 6, 30, 30)];
                market.tag = 4000;

                [market addTarget:self action:@selector(marketPressedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

                [cell.contentView addSubview:market];
                 UILabel *pricelabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 0, 80, 30)];
            pricelabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            pricelabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];
            pricelabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
            pricelabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
            pricelabel.tag = 3000;
            //pricelabel.hidden = YES;
            pricelabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
            [cell.contentView addSubview: pricelabel];
            [pricelabel release];
           }

            UIButton *marketButton = (UIButton*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:4000];
            [marketButton setTag:indexPath.row];
            if([sellingArray count]>0)
            {
                NSLog(@"sellingArray %@",sellingArray);
                if([[sellingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"0"]) // nothing
                {

                    [marketButton setSelected:NO];
                    [marketButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Marketplace.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    marketButton.enabled = YES;

                }
                else if([[sellingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"2"])  // marketplace
                {
                    [marketButton setSelected:YES];
                    [marketButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MarketplaceSelect.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    marketButton.enabled = YES;

                }
            }

            }
         UILabel *pricelbl = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3000];
           pricelbl.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@",[priceNewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
            if ([sellingArray count]>0) {
               if([[sellingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"2"]){

                    pricelbl.hidden = NO;
                }
                else if([[sellingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"0"]){
                    pricelbl.hidden = YES;

            }


            }
            return cell;
        }
```

marketpressAction :

```
  - (void)marketPressedAction:(id)sender
{
    buttonPressed = (UIButton *)sender;
    buttontag = buttonPressed.tag;
    NSLog(@"Market button click at row %d",buttontag);

}
```

Comment: You are changing the tag of the button from 4000 to `[marketButton setTag:indexPath.row];` twice in the code above. Don't change it.

Comment: @Amar: Sorry, i edited my code. Please check it. I remove [marketButton setTag:indexPath.row]; , when click on this button, my app crash

Comment: You code is kind of a mess. What is cell.button? Does the cell already have a button you made in IB? Every time this method runs, you are adding a new Market button, even if the cell already has one. Since you have a custom cell, it would be easier, and your code a lot simpler, to add all the subviews in IB, and make outlets to them in your custom cell class.

Comment: @rdelmar: i tried my code but image is overload

Comment: You tried what? What do you mean, "image is overload", that makes no sense to me.

Comment: Oh sorry, i mean when reloadData, image of button is duplicate